# What is the tensor power series of a vector?

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, tensor-products, online-resources, jet-bundles

In this Wikipedia article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics) there’s Taylor’s theorem for functions $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $f(x)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} D^n f(x_0) (x-x_0)^{\otimes n} /n!$.

What does this tensor product mean here and where can I learn more about it?

If it’s just the normal krownecker/tensor  product, then how do they sum to a vector?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kronecker Products and Powers notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169312/kronecker-products-and-powers-notation)

Comment: See [In multivariate Taylor expansion formula, what is meant by $(x−a)^k$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3631316/568204). Sure, there, they didn't use the tensor product symbol, but the meaning is exactly the same (also in that answer I use the notation $d^nf(a)$, which is the same thing as $D^nf(a)$). Or a [similar answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4177847/568204) in more detail.